# Eclipse cannot connect to remote git server via ssh egit funny refname [remote rejected]

Tags: eclipse, git, egit, head, gerrit

I have set up a git repository through `Gerrit`. I am trying push my local repository to a remote one i just created with `Gerrit (ssh Linux box).` I have imported my RSA keys into both Gerrit and Eclipse set up repository settings. When I try and Push to Upstream I get

```
/refs/for/master: HEAD [remote rejected]
```

**Repository**

```
ssh://<Username>@<IP Address>:<Port>/<repository name>
```

funny refname

what is 'funny refname` and how can I get a secure connection within eclipse?

Comment: Please paste the remote section of `.git/config` from the local repository here.

Comment: [core]repositoryformatversion = 0
 filemode = false
 logallrefupdates = true
[remote "origin"]
 url = ssh://<username>@<IP>:<port>/<repo name>
 fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
 pushurl = ssh://<username>@<IP>:<port>/<repo name>
 push = HEAD:/refs/for/master
 push = refs/heads/master:refs/heads/master
[branch "master"]
 remote = origin
 merge = refs/heads/master
[branch]
[gerrit]
 createchangeid = true

Comment: Please update the question instead of pasting it in the comment, it's not very readable like this.

Answer (score 0):

A "funny refname" is Git's way of saying that the ref name you are trying to push to is invalid.

You seem to have the following configuration in the remote section (in `.git/config`):

```
push = HEAD:/refs/for/master
```

It should instead be:

```
push = HEAD:refs/for/master
```